# NullPointerException on setText() method

Tags: android, textview, nullpointerexception

I have a strange problem I don't understand...

I want to do a PopupWindow from an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/popup" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#404040"
android:padding="15px">

<TextView android:id="@+id/popup_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" 
    android:textSize="16dip" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and I just want to do a so simple thing: set the text in my TextView... Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

//UI
ui = new RelativeLayout(this);
ui.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
setContentView(ui);

//PopUp
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
popUp = new PopupWindow(this);
popUp.setContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_piece, ui, false));


    //Boutton
    bouton = new Button(this);
    bouton.setText("POWPEUP");
    ui.addView(bouton);

    bouton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            popUp.showAtLocation(ui, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            popUp.update(0, 0, 350, 400);

            titrePopUp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.popup_title); // THIS RETURNS NULL
            Log.d("TextView", ""+titrePopUp);
                            //titrePopUp.setText("blop", TextView.BufferType.NORMAL); SO THIS DONT WORK
        }
    });
}
```

Seriously, I don't understand why it returns a NULL value.. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: where have u put `popup_piece` i don't see it in your layout..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are searching for the TextView in your main layout, not in the PopupWindow. You need to do this instead:

```
titrePopUp = (TextView) popUp.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popup_titre);
```

Answer (score 3):

In layout id is spelled as `popup_title`, and in code it's spelled as `popup_titre`. Maybe, this is the problem.

Comment: Well, that's just an error of copy.. I'm programming in french and I translate it for asking my questions.. The real name is popup_titre

Comment: @Greg OK. If I understood your intent right, you want to show a TextView on an Button's click. Why don't you use Toasts? However, your approach is not right. You should findViewById() when initializing your layout, and change the visibility of the TextView on buttons click.

Comment: I don't use Toast because my PopupWindow will contains an ImageView and another TextView. By the way, I found the solution to my problem with the answer of Graham. Thanks a lot for you help!